# How can you have a maths equation in a list and have it print out the result?

Tags: list, python-3.x

Here's an example:

```
a = [] #a is an empty list 
a.append(input())  #input is 5*5
print(a[0])
5*5
```

How can I print(a[0]) so it works out 5*5 with the result being 25? Is there any way?
Thank you

Comment: This is a complex topic, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The programmer in me hates the following piece of code but if you trust the input, it works well

```
print(eval(a[0]))
```

`eval` tries to treat the string as an expression and evaluate it. In this case, the string `'5*5'` is treated as simply the python expression `5*5` and outputs

```
25
```

Comment: Don't **ever** allow users to provide input for the system `eval()`, bad things can and will happen.

Comment: Thank you so much, You're a life saver. I did vote up your comment but apparently It doesn't show due to being new to the site.

Comment: Care to explain @zwer?

Comment: It takes the code inside the string, and literally executes it. Which is why `eval("5*5")` works. It returns the value of the statement`5*5`. Now you can run ANY code you want, by typing things such as `coins = "500000000000000"`, if the eval statement isn't used correctly.

Comment: @zwer is 95% correct. This is not good practice. It depends where your input is coming from and the context in which it runs. There are a number of scenarios that this works really well - even on a project I'm currently working on. How you separate this code from the rest of your code is important.

That being said, I believe it answers the immediate question around how to execute that expression.

Comment: @Tobi, I'm getting the result I was after. I'm a newby doing newby little things. This answered my question perfectly.

Comment: @Easter - read, for example, [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: I'm just saying this is a very lazy solution, that can very easily go wrong. I understand that you're probably contempt with it.

Comment: @Easter I'm glad it gave you what you need. Consider the other comments to this answer and if you ever start asking yourself 'is this safe', search for some more material on StackOverflow to perhaps find a new way of doing this. For now, I think you'll be good.

Good luck!

Comment: @Tobi - I believe you have the option of providing an alternative answer :-). I'd think the comment you made was fairly lazy itself....

Comment: I appreciate all the answers, Time to sleep as I've spent too long trying to figure this out. One last question: If I think of a little script to make but after hours on hours I can't figure out how to do everything. Is it better to look at someone elses script and see what they did or ask questions on the things i don't know and go from there?

Comment: @Easter - I'm assuming you mean specifically in the context of Stackoverflow.

The steps are:
1. Try it yourself. Mess around, try and get a nitty gritty feel for how it works. You can do this in a python shell (or, better yet, an iPython shell).
2. If you don't come right, Google and see what other people are doing. Search terms are a skill so try and change up what you're searching for. Look at other peoples' implementations and try to replicate them. Break them a part to truly understand.
3. Search Stackoverflow for a similar question
4. After all of that, then open your own question.

Comment: Thank you @KyleO'Brien. Appreciate your time